# How to convert file format to utf-8 in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, vim, utf-8

I have a CSV file with Chinese characters and it is showing a lot of hex codes and unreadable characters like this when I open my file in vim: `é<80><80>è´§,5896,1.0,é<80><80>è´§ <8d><95>`

How do I read this file properly? I was thinking of using `iconv` but I don't know the file format. I am using `zsh` so when I tried this command to get file format:

`myfile.csv /etc/passwd`

This is the error I got:
`zsh: command not found`

Could it be an issue with my zshprofile or bash_profile?
In my zshrc profile: `vim ~me/.zshrc`

This is the only thing I have uncommented:

```
export LC_CTYPE=C
export LANG=C
```

In bash_profile:

```
#export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
#export LOCALE=UTF-8

export LC_CTYPE=C
export LANG=C
```

`cat myfile.csv` outputs the chinese characters fine on terminal.

Comment: What Linux Distro and version of VIM are you using?

Comment: Just `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, and comment/remove all other `LANG` and `LC_CTYPE` definitions. Make sure `locale` completes without errors

Comment: im on mac osx and the vim version is: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 13 2015 13:50:51)
`

Comment: also the unreadable characters only appear after i `tail` multiple files (of which all appear normal in vim)  together and output them to a new file.

Comment: the `set encoding=utf-8` into your `~/.vimrc` doesn't helps?

Comment: After the file is opened, what does `vim` say if you ask `:set fenc?` and `:set fencs?`?

Comment: set fencs is `fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1`

Comment: Then either your `enca` and `file` are mistaken, or you have gibberish file. While your file is loaded, try `:e ++big5`, `:e ++gb2312`, `:e ++gb2312`, and see if any of these shows you something recognisable. (You can open the file forcing an encoding using `:e filename++encoding`; if you leave out the filename, it reopens the current file.)

Comment: Oops, sorry - the syntax is `:e ++enc=big5` (and `:e ++enc=encoding filename`). And another - the file does appear to be UTF-8. (When I tested your fragment, it comes out as `退货,5896,1.0,退货 ??`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
file -bi myfile.csv
```

for showing the encoding of your file.
Unfortunately it is not always easy to tell which encoding is used within a file.
If file -bi does not output something useful for your case, please post the result.

Comment: the output of the above is just `regular file`

Comment: how do i install it if im using zsh?

Comment: It depends from your linux distribution. In debian you use apt-get (apt-get install enca) in suse you use Yast. Please note, that you need root privileges to install software.

Comment: output of `enca myfile.csv -L none` is
`Universal transformation format 8 bits; UTF-8`

Comment: @jxn, Then there is no need to convert to UTF-8 as it's already UTF-8.

Comment: how do i convert 7bit ASCII characters file to utf-8 with enca?

Comment: This is not an answer, but a request for more information - it should be a comment.

Comment: Wrong. The OP asks also how to determin the right encoding of his file